# How to give general users access to programs installed in another user area, not global directory

Tags: paths, installed-programs

I've installed a package (according to the instructions) but noticed it didn't install the binary into the `/usr/bin` directory, but instead into the user area.

What's the best way to give other users access to this particular path without necessarily giving everyone `sudo` access?
Adding the path into their `.profile` file?

Thanks in advance for any responses.
Much appreciated :)

Comment: Is it only one folder in `/home/user-name` ? Which program is it? You might want to include this information into your question.

Comment: What's the problem to install binary for all? You just seems to not fully understood instructions.

Comment: @user3417815 please not assume to quick inability on the questioners side, not every package you can compile from source, or get as a tarball. Best example here is steam. You only get a `.deb` file and it installs, guess where, in your home folder.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. The program is Tripos's SYBYLx2.1 - a computational chemistry package for Linux.(Didn't include program details because it is not common unless you are doing this type of work). The instructions suggested to create a Tripos user account and install there, which I did. So it's now installed into Tripos' /home/sybylx2.1/ It was a self-extracting install file. Not sure if this makes it any clearer. Amy help much appreciated. THanks

Answer (score 0):

**Remind to make a backup of the application folder before changing around things, and that you need to restart to make the new `$PATH` setting take effect.**

**Ive written this answer based on the sparse information given and it might or might not work**

You can move that installation probably into the `/opt/` directory and then adding it to the path variable. The following I write under the assumption that it is all in one folder inside your `/home/user-name` directory and that the user specific data is written into a `~/.config/` subdirectory.

```bsh
sudo mv /home/"$USER"/<application-folder> /opt/
sudo chown -R root:root /opt/<application-folder>
```

Now when you moved the whole thing and changed the ownership add `PATH="/opt/<application-folder>:$PATH"` to the `~/.profile` file and same for every user being allowed to use this application. Do so by:

```bsh
# in case of your own .profile
echo "PATH="/opt/<application-folder>:$PATH"" >> ~/.profile

# in case of the other users .profile
echo "PATH="/opt/<application-folder>:$PATH"" | sudo tee -a /home/<user-name>/.profile
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking time to explain how to do this. Much appreciated. The software is a computational chemistry package by Tripos called Sybylx2.1. The instructions suggested 1st creating a Tripos user and install from there. They also advised prior to installation to chmod for execution by all group members. So I've included the appropriate users into the 'Tripos' group. The program self extracted & installed into one directory (/home/sybylx2.1/).  Thanks again for your detailed answer and I'll be sure to remember to back up the application prior to any changes. Cheers

Comment: If it doesn't work out as expected just holler and I'll try to find another solution. However if it works and my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the check-mark beside it. :)

Comment: Will do, thanks. I'll give it a whirl today :)